# How to select the row in same value and then make them with same ordering (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to map the row with same figure and then give the row with same ordering.

Wish i can post pictures to explain it~ .

As you might see, the ording 0 is matched with 3 , and ording 4 is matched with 6 and so on.

```
Ording, Dr, Cr  
0, 3200,  0  
1,    0,  30  
2,   50,  0  
3,    0,  3200  
4, 1700,  0  
5,    0,  20  
6,   0,  1700  
7,   30,  0   
8,    0,  50  
9,  100,  0   
10,   0, 30   
11,   0, 30  
12,   0, 30  
13,   0, 40  
14,   50, 0
```

**My question is HOW to map the same value in Dr and Cr columns with same ordering. For others don't append in pair just give the same order like "1".**

P.S. The numeric values giving to these pairs are arbitrary.
As long as the pairs get the same ording number.

Below is what I am looking forward to.
I have tried to use " Sort_Value" or "Groupby" and even "eq()"; however, I cannot get what I want.

```
2, 3200,  0  
3,    0,  30   
4,   50,  0   
2,    0,  3200  
5, 1700,  0  
1,    0,  20  
5,   0,  1700  
3,   30,  0   
4,    0,  50  
1,  100,  0   
1,   0, 30   
1,   0, 30 
1,   0, 30  
1,   0, 40  
1,   50, 0
```

In case someone don't understand what the final result look like.
I sort ordering to make it's easier to read.

```
1,  100,  0   
1,   0, 30   
1,   0, 30   
1,   0, 30   
1,   0, 40   
1,   50, 0    
1,    0,  20   
2, 3200,  0     
2,    0,  3200    
3,    0,  30  
3,   30,  0  
4,   50,  0  
4,    0,  50     
5, 1700,  0  
5,   0,  1700
```

Please share your view if you have any idea.

Comment: Please take a moment and explain your data better - which part is what in one line?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please edit the question and explain the rationale of how you get from the input to the desired output?

Comment: Please include both the sample data and the expected output **as text** in the question so others can reproduce it.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. I have edited the question.
Original
https://imgur.com/BQ386p4
Goal
https://imgur.com/eVb0kRy

Comment: How do you get the numbers in the first column? why does (3200, 0) get the value "2", and (0, 30) get the value 3?

Comment: Thanks for asking. (3200, 0) get the value "2", and (0, 30) get the value 3 are what I am working for~ I still don't know how to do it, so I post online ask for help. 
Sorry for vague question, i edited the question again.

Comment: So the numeric values you're giving to these pairs are arbitrary? Can it be 3 and 2 for 3200 and 30 respectively, instead of the opposite order?

Comment: YES, you can give pairs in arbitrary values~!! As long as pairs get same ordering number.
Thank for remind. I will add it in question.

Comment: Can you have more than one pair of identical values? For example 0-3, 3-0, 0-3, 3-0?

Comment: Yes, having more  than one pair with same ordering is fine.